# Post data from non-admin user in WordPress

Tags: post, wordpress, save

I'm speaking of "post" as in the html method, not a blog post. This overlap in terminology is probably a good part of the reason I can't find what I'm looking for.

I have some admin pages set up with forms, using `add_action('admin_post_something', 'my_function');` to handle saving the form data to the database. That all works marvelously.

Now I have a client-side piece that requires the user to be logged in to post data, but not necessarily be an admin. The `admin_post_something` hook will not work (returns page not found) because the user is not an admin. This is expected behavior.

What hook action should I use to process and store information coming from the client-facing portion of my site, and where should this function be located? Examples or links to documentation are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So, you're letting your non-admin users submit data using the POST method via the front-end? What are you doing with the data, are you updating a WordPress page or post? or doing something else? The specific hook you use will be dependant on what you're actually doing.

Comment: @henrywright I've created a simple plugin which allows users to sign up for activities in time slots. The admin pages create the options for activities and time slots, then a third database table associates users to indicated activity/time-slots pairs. So the post data will associate a selected `activity_id` and `timeslot_id` with the current users `wp_users_id` in a table. There will be a second function to remove this row from the table only if current user id matches the stored row id.

Comment: So you will have a function somewhere (perhaps in your plugin or perhaps in functions.php) that performs the processing of the POST data. Inside that function you could just add a conditional to check if the form has been submitted. For example: `if ( isset( $_POST['your-hidden-field-name-in-your-form'] ) ) { // do something here because the form has been submitted }`

Comment: @henrywright that makes sense. Would you put that out as an answer? I'll give you some kudos.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your function which processes the POST data, you could have a conditional check to see if the form has been submitted. For example:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['a-hidden-field-name-in-your-form'] ) ) { 
    // do something here because the form has been submitted 
}
```